# What is the best slideshow to CCK image field?

Tags: entities, media

I would like to know your suggestions about the best slideshow module to images uploaded from CCK image field. When I mean best, I want to say **quality/quantity of features supported** according your experience, but if you know another criteria (like support), please feel free to give your suggestion according your criteria.

Comment: plese feel free to warn about possible duplicate question. I can not find recomendations in 'Search results' or 'Similar Question' list.

Comment: to avoid having ur question closed, as this is more opinion than fact. can you elaborate on ur question to isolate the features you are looking for in particular?

Comment: thank you for your warn. yes I want to find opinions, due that the human brain can, like you know (additionally to answer, according facts) can answer specific information using incomplete(and/or)vague(and/or)relative(and/or)generalistic information. ¿and why here? this is the best place to know experiences of people interacting with Drupal.

to avoid closed my question, I will edit it to be more specific.

Comment: I agree that this is a valid question, but as it is written, it is best for forums on D.O, rather than Q/A on DSE. Better to specify what you need in one, rather than a wiki-style comparison that creates a lot of discussion (much like this one now).

Comment: Nigel, thanks for your time to talk me about a good practice to make questions in DSE, I am newbie in DSE, and also in this model of Q/A sites. Can you tell me what is the meaning of D.O?

Comment: D.O. stands for drupal.org

Comment: If is possible I will wait one day to know if exist some answers. this is possible? or do you recommend delete my question?. I can delete if you ask. like I say, I am newbie in this Q/A model.

Comment: See what happens. :) I have answers to give, but the question is too vague for me to determine which one would best suit your situation. Personally, most module choices are not dictated by the overall features, but rather the use-case, especially in the case of photo/slideshow/gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is of course this page in the drupal docs: http://drupal.org/node/418616

Unless you have a very specific use case which can be accommodated by a specialized module you really should go with the views slideshow module (http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). Very well maintained, fairly well documented (but a lot of tutorials flying around) and a lot of modules integrating with it. With this module you can do almost everything slideshow-wise but it might be a bit complicated (but again: lots of tutorials available).

You can of course check out some of the other modules if they offer something more matching to your specific needs.

Comment: very useful resource!

Comment: dddave thanks for your recomendations, is a interesting list, plenty of descriptions and criterias.